# php remove strings from array with certain length

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to work out how to use array filter to remove strings from array below a certain length.

Basicly I want to recreate this with array filter,

```
if( strlen($news_ps[$x]) < 5))
   { 
      remove this string from array
   }
```

Comment: Try [array filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = array_filter(
    $originalArray,
    function ($value) {
        return strlen($value) >= 5;
    }
);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to reorder the indexes as well, then just wrap the whole in a call to array_values()

```
$result = array_values(
    array_filter(
        $originalArray,
        function ($value) {
            return strlen($value) >= 5;
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Sort of works, can you get it to reorder the indexes?

Answer (score -1):

```
function lessthan5($v){
     if(intval($v) > 5){
       return $v;
    } 

}
print_r(array_filter(array(3,4,5,6,7) ,"lessthan5"));

//out put
Array ( [3] => 6 [4] => 7 )
```